Large deviations and phase space path integral
For each natural number $N$ consider $Q_N$ the Berezin-Toeplitz quantization map, assigning to each continuous function $f$ on the unit two sphere $S^2$ an $(N+1)$-dimensional matrix denoted by $Q_N(f)$,
$$Q_N: C(S^2)\to M_{N+1}(\mathbb{C}^2),$$
given by
$$Q_N(f):=\frac{N+1}{4\pi}\int_{S^2}d\mu(\Omega) f(\Omega)|\Omega\rangle\langle\Omega|_N,$$
where $\mu$ is the standard measure on $S^2$, and $|\Omega\rangle\langle\Omega|_N$ is the one-dimensional projection (bra-ket notation) onto the linear span of the spin-coherent state vector $|\Omega\rangle_N$, labeled by the point $\Omega\in S^2$. These vectors are also called $SU(2)$ coherent states
I am interested in the following asymptotics:
$$\frac{1}{N}\log{\langle \Omega, e^{NQ_N(f)}\Omega\rangle_N}, \ \ \ \ N\to\infty\ \ (*)$$
More precisely, I wish to prove that this limit exists uniformly independent of the chosen point $\Omega$, as $N\to\infty$.
My ideas:
(i) A phase space path integral formula may be explored in order to write
$$\langle \Omega, e^{NQ_N(f)}\Omega\rangle_N, \ \ \ (**) $$
as a path integral, defined in terms of a Wiener measure and a Brownian bridge process. There is literature on this topic, but most of it is non-rigorous. Does there really exist a well-defined path integral formulation for (**) ?
(ii) If such a path integral formulation would indeed exist, I believe it is not that difficult anymore to prove the convergence of (*), since one may rely on known results (e.g. by Varadhan) on large deviation principles.
I appreciate all comments and suggestions.
